# Can one modelName.php and one ModelNameController.php handle multiple identical (or similar) tables?

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to have one modelName.php and one ModelNameController.php to handle multiple identical (or similar) tables, using dynamic table names? I'm thinking a multi-player game with many rounds, each player can only play once per round (his "draw" in each round consists of "plays"). If rounds require a model/controller each, with daily play that would be 730 files in a year. I've spent numerous hours studying similarly worded questions, but none seems directly analogous to mine (except one that nobody answered).

Comment: are you planning on creating a new table for each round or something?

Comment: @lagbox, Yes, each round would create a daily table, e.g. round_1, round_2, etc. So in a year, there would be about 365 (~identical) tables (different data of course). But I was trying to avoid creating a model and controller for each table. Each player plays once (one draw of several plays) per round. I've toyed with combining all the draws into one big table with round_id field, but it seemed unwieldy. I was thinking if all the tables have the same fields, dynamic names for them could work. I don't know if it can be done or what other adverse effects there might be cause I'm a noob. Thanks.